# Load PATCH data with Marshmallow without validating missing fields

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm trying to implement a `PATCH` route for the following SQLAlchemy model and Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy schema. I want to update `description`, `address`, or both.
When I send the only one field in the data and try to load it, Marshmallow says the other field is missing. How can I load patch data with Marshmallow without it validating missing fields?

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    description = db.Column(db.String(180))
    address = db.Column(db.String(180))


class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        load_only = ("password",)
        dump_only = ("id",)
```

```
{
    "description": "New Description"
}
```

```py
user_data = user_schema.load(request.get_json())
```

```
{
    "username": [
        "Missing data for required field."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it `username` or `name`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is PATCH you can pass your model instance and flag `partial=True` to the schema.

```
user_data = user_schema.load(request.get_json(), instance=instance, partial=True)
```